# App crashes with a java.lang.NullPointerException while open a screen with a GoogleMaps widget multiple time

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

Despite adding a dispose method and a future delay, the app continues to crash when opening Google Maps multiple times.
plugin:- google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.5;
plugin:- custom_info_window: ^1.0.1;
flutter version:- 3.3.4

```
  CustomInfoWindowController _customInfoWindowController = CustomInfoWindowController();
```

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    _customInfoWindowController.dispose();
    _customInfoWindowController.googleMapController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wrrj.jpg)

```
GoogleMap(
            onTap: (position) {
              _customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow!();
            },
            onCameraMove: (position) {
              _customInfoWindowController.onCameraMove!();
            },
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
              _customInfoWindowController.googleMapController = controller;
            },
            markers: markers,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(dataToShowOnMap[0].latitude, dataToShowOnMap[0].longitude),
              zoom: 15,
            ),
          )
```

I have added a delay before opening and closing the map as well.
  `Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {});`

Answer (score 0):

The variable declarations are missing here so unable to debug more on it.

You could try checking the markers array values and value of dataToShowOnMap while initialising and before rendering the Google Map.

Comment: just add dummy latitude and longitude